# Minimum and maximum weight / weights is/are indicative only

Tags: adjectives, subject-verb-agreement

I don't know how to solve the agreement in this sentence:

> Minimum and maximum weight / weights is/are indicative only.

Edit:

It's from an article about peaches. The text says that the minimum weight is 100 g and the maximum weight is 130 g (but the minimum and maximum weight/weights is/are indicative only)

Comment: more context will be helpful.

Comment: Is the article available online? Can you provide a link to it?

Answer (score 3):

There's typically no need for the conditionals, if it's a overarching statement over some terms and conditions. Whether there are, for any individual instances, either a minimum or maximum weight only then the statement still works sensibly.

> Minimum and maximum weights are indicative only.